# What is eating up space inside Final Cut X bundles?

Tags: macos, finder, final-cut-pro

So here is the deal: I am backing up my HD, deleting all the media and keeping just the bundles. Usually it takes no more than 2MB, maybe 5MB. However some bundles are getting 10x more space. Like this one:

[image]

Often it is just about embedded render files (and then it can take several GB). No problem, I just get inside the package and delete the Render folder.

[image]

Now what is really odd, is that inside some packages, there is nothing using that space.

[image]

As you can see, I have already enabled hidden files to display.
Could it be some sort of Finder refreshing issue?

This is my system:
[image]

Comment: Does https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/229522/why-is-my-final-cut-pro-library-file-so-bloated help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weird behavior, but I guess it was my fault.

At first, the solution [apple.stackexchange.com/questions/229522/…](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/229522/why-is-my-final-cut-pro-library-file-so-bloated) proposed by [@Graham Miln](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/1860/graham-miln) didn't work.

It should flush all renders, proxies, etc.

But before trying that I had deleted the render files manually inside the bundle (and also from the trash).

So maybe because the bundle had been open inside Final Cut in the current session, it was holding some information about the project, even being "closed".

Since FCP saves after everything you do (in fact we cannot decide to change this behavior, which is shameful), when you quit the program it saves the last state of the package, so maybe that was the issue.

Today I did the same thing, using the program's interface, but I quit FCP before inspecting the package.

Since FCP saves everything you do (in fact we cannot decide to change this behavior, which is shameful), when you quit the program it saves the last state of the package, so perhaps that was the issue.

Now it has just 460KB.

[image]